# SQL query - Count Job ID for Customer ID and Date

Tags: sql, count

I need some help to count the number of `job_id` values for my specific `customer_id` and group them in the right date column.

The table looks like this (it only contains data for the last 3 months):

| customer_id | job_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 01-01-2024 |
| 1 | 102 | 12-12-2023 |
| 1 | 103 | 10-11-2023 |
| 2 | 104 | 25-12-2023 |
| 2 | 105 | 01-01-2024 |
| 1 | 106 | 01-12-2023 |
| 2 | 107 | 15-11-2023 |

I would like the query to be like this: a `job_id` count for each `customer_id`, and a count for each month the `job_id` is created.

| customer_id | job_id | Nov-23 | Dec-23 | Jan-24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific functionality might be handy here.)

Comment: Do you really want 90+ columns? (For three months.)

Answer (score 1):

To get the required output, you can use conditional aggregation, also known as a pivot query. Here's how:

```
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    COUNT(job_id) AS total_jobs,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2nd_last_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS current_month
FROM Table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%d-%m-%Y') <= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pJAJm9dJzGcq5pDGPm7pKV/0

Comment: Are you sure OP is using MySQL/MariaDB?